# Config webpack to generate scss to css

Tags: webpack, sass

I'm searching on the oficial doc but I'm not sure how it works , how Can I set the entry to get the scss files and the output to the generated css files, with this `webpack.config.js` only works the js part but the par of sass-loader its like if not exists,  with `px webpack --watch --color` command the taks it's executed with no errors, but there is no css files generated

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'main.js':[
      './src/js/index.js',
      './src/js/second.js',
    ],
    'third.js':'./src/js/third.js'  
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js'),
  },
  mode: 'development',
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "public/css/styles.css"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you importing `.scss` files in `index.js`, `second.js` or `third.js` dependency tree?

Comment: Also, is `public/css/styles.css` genereated after build?

Comment: `public/css/styles.css`it's not generated

Comment: How can I import this files?